# i have 2 spinner and then add document button, image saved without taking spinner value

Tags: android

I have  2 spinner and then add document button, image saved without taking spinner value

I am trying to make a xml file which store spinner database, and call the values when we want to view

```
    {

 public class MainActivity extends Activity implements
            AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {
        Spinner s1, s2;
        private Button btn;
        private ImageView imageview;
        private static final String IMAGE_DIRECTORY = "/demon";
        private int GALLERY = 1;
        private int CAMERA = 2;

        Intent intent;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            s1 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
            s2 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner2);
            btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);

            btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    showPictureDialog();
                }
            });
            s1.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
        }

        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                                   long arg3) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            String sp1 = String.valueOf(s1.getSelectedItem());
            Toast.makeText(this, sp1, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            if (sp1.contentEquals("Identity Documents")) {
                List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
                list.add("PAN Card\n");
                list.add("Passport\n");                                           

ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                        android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, list);
                dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
                dataAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                s2.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
            }

public void choosePhotoFromGallary() {
            Intent galleryIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,
                    android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);

            startActivityForResult(galleryIntent, GALLERY);
        }

@Override
        public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
            if (resultCode == this.RESULT_CANCELED) {
                return;
            }
            if (requestCode == GALLERY) {
                if (data != null) {
                    Uri contentURI = data.getData();
                    try {
                        Bitmap bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(this.getContentResolver(), contentURI);
                        String path = saveImage(bitmap);
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Image Saved!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        imageview.setImageBitmap(bitmap);


                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Failed!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }


        public String saveImage(Bitmap myBitmap) {
            ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            myBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, bytes);
            File wallpaperDirectory = new File(
                    Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + IMAGE_DIRECTORY);
            // have the object build the directory structure, if needed.
            if (!wallpaperDirectory.exists()) {
                wallpaperDirectory.mkdirs();
            }

            try {
                File f = new File(wallpaperDirectory, Calendar.getInstance()
                        .getTimeInMillis() + ".jpg");
                f.createNewFile();
                FileOutputStream fo = new FileOutputStream(f);
                fo.write(bytes.toByteArray());
                MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(this,
                        new String[]{f.getPath()},
                        new String[]{"image/jpeg"}, null);
                fo.close();
                Log.d("TAG", "File Saved::--->" + f.getAbsolutePath());

                return f.getAbsolutePath();
            } catch (IOException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
            return "";

        }


    }
            }
```

I want to create db of this spinner in another xml file to get value when select spinner next time.

Comment: Please elaborate your question

Comment: i have 2 spinner and 1 button which save my file but, when i press button my file get saved but , files are saving without taking values of spinner i need to know how to store values of spinner while saving file , so after that when i select spinner in next activity then my specific file that are linked to spinner will shown